# 'this' reference in angular asynchronous calls vs react and node asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, callback, this

Why does **this** in angular's **this.http.subscribe** body references the current component while **this** in react or node's nested asynchronous callbacks references the http request itself? What can i do to achieve the angular pattern?

Comment: You understanding is off. It completely depends on the execution context.

Comment: That's what I'm asking here. How does angular create a context and how can we keep the reference to global while in nested asynchronous loops.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the angular pattern you can add a `that = this;`  before the subscribe (in the method body). Then reference it in the subscribe.